# Run evaluation after part of a training epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I load two datasets with the dataset api, one for training and one for evaluation. I switch between them with `sess.run(train_init_op)` before running the evaluation or training.

Currently I run the evaluation after finishing one epoch, i.e. after the training dataset was run through completely.

If I want to evaluate my network before the training dataset was finished, I would have to switch earlier, and by doing this tensorflow would forget where it has been in the training dataset. Is there any way to remember the state of the training dataset iterator? And switch back to this position after the evaluation has finished?

Comment: have you considered using the estimator api? It can perform evaluation during training if you correctly configure either the [InMemoryEvaluatorHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.9/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/InMemoryEvaluatorHook) or [train_and_evaluate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate) method?

Comment: Estimator API was quite a big change in my code structure, but in the end I did that. Seemed like the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not only about remembering the position in the training set, but also accumulated gradients, params of an optimizer (if you use something like Adam) etc. Switching context between training and validation can be tricky.

For instance, in Google object detection API there is a separate validation process that [monitors for fresh checkpoints](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/eval_util.py#L453) and run validation on them. Meanwhile training is running further. Thus, by setting the checkpoint interval you can achieve any validation frequency you want.